# How do I deploy a simple React app as a "user page" to Github Pages?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I've looked at numerous StackOverflow answers, that answer a variety of different scenarios regarding publishing React pages to Github, but none of them clearly explain how to publish a basic user page. I have a very simple, standard React app, that I'd like to publish as a user page on Github.

What are the basic steps for publishing a simple React app as a **user page** to Github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, in total, is found in two document sources.

Presuming that you've already created your React app, all is well locally, and your app is ready to deploy, here are the steps to deploy a simple React app as a ***user page*** on Github:

1. Follow the guidance given by [Github regarding Github Pages](https://guides.github.com/features/pages/#:%7E:text=Create%20Your%20Website,-Once%20you%27ve&text=On%20the%20new%20repository%20screen,name%20to%20generate%20your%20website.&text=If%20you%20scroll%20down%20on,process%20of%20creating%20your%20site.)... in particular, note that ***user pages*** are served *only* from the `master` branch, and thus, the user page will be served at `https://{your-github-user-name}.github.io`.

> User pages must be built from the master branch.

2. Next, follow the guidance provided in [Create React Apps documentation regarding Github Pages deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#step-1-add-homepage-to-packagejson), particularly the parts related to ***user pages***.

> *Open your package.json and add a `homepage` field that matches where your user page will be served from:*

`"homepage": "https://myusername.github.io",`

> *Install the gh-pages module:*

`npm install --save gh-pages` ... or ... `yarn add gh-pages`

> *Add `deploy` (and `predeploy`) to `scripts` in package.json:*

```
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    ... 
  },
```

> *Modify your `deploy` script to force push the built application to the `master` branch:*

`"deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build",`

> *Deploy your site by running:*

`npm run deploy`

3. The last obstacle to overcome, is caching at Github. You might need to run `npm run deploy` more than once, to get around Github's caching of previous deploys.

Comment: excellent answer. its word emphasizing that the github repo name has to be `your-github-username.gitub.io`. from the first link you provided: `Enter username.github.io as the repository name. Replace username with your GitHub username. For example, if your username is octocat, the repository name should be octocat.github.io. `