# How do I deploy react app on user pages (Github)?

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment

I am trying to deploy a react app, but specifically on user page on github pages. I can see a LOT of resources for deploying to project page, but nothing yet for user page. Please help!!!

I have tried switching the gh-pages line in the package.json file to include master, but even then I will have to update the gh-pages branch, it doesn't deploy directly from master. I want to be able to deploy directly from master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`gitname/react-gh-pages`](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages) is one good example, and applies to a user site, where GitHub requires that the repository's name have the following format: `{username}.github.io` (e.g. `gitname.github.io`).

But it uses the `gh-pages` branch as [publication source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site), not `master` (which no longer exists anyway, since [it was renamed to main](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-the-default-branch-for-newly-created-repositories-is-now-main/) since Oct. 2020)

---

The [OP cheese-berry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14552078/cheese-berry) references in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74957609/how-do-i-deploy-react-app-on-user-pages-github/74972605#comment132328499_74972605) the post "[How do I deploy a simple React app as a "user page" to Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62734626/6309)"

cheese-berry adds:

> For anyone else with the same question, you need to basically:
>
> - pay attention to your repo name,
> - install the `gh-pages` package,
> - modify your `package.json` file, and
> - change your source of deployment on GitHub (Repo -> Settings -> Pages -> Build & Deployment).

Comment: Thank you! I followed a bit of this, and then found the direct link within that menu (it's under "Quickstart for github pages"

Link: shorturl.at/clHX0

For anyone else with the same q, you need to basically pay attention to your repo name, install the gh-pages package, modify your package.json file, and change your source of deployment on github (Repo -> Settings -> Pages -> Build & Deployment).